# Issues filling an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to fill an array with the unique values from another file. This file has about 20 integers total, 10 are unique and 10 are copies. The user inputs the size of the array and name of the file within the main.

I think the trouble is coming from this while loop that is meant to fill the array, sorting out the duplicates.

At the moment, it only successfully sorts 11 of the 20 integers in the file.

```
private static int read(String inFileName, int[] list) {
        int size = 0;
        int i= 0;

        Scanner inFile = null;
        int val = 0;

        int trash = 0;
        boolean ID = false;
        int Unique = 0;
        int dupe = 0;
        int lineCount = 0;

        try { 
            inFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
            while (inFile.hasNext()){
                lineCount++;
                try{
                    val = inFile.nextInt();
                    if(val < 0) { 
                        trash++;
                        continue; 
                    }

                    for(i = 0; i< size ;i++){ 
                        if(list[i] == val){
                            ID = true;
                            dupe++;
               
                        }

                    }
                    if (ID == false && size<list.length){ 
                        list[size] = val;
                        size++;
                        Unique++;
                    }

                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e){
                    trash++;
                    inFile.nextLine();
                }

            }
            System.out.println("lines: " + lineCount + ", unique: " + Unique +  ", dupes: " + dupe + ", trash: " + trash);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in opening " + inFileName);
        }


        return size;
    }
```

So far, I have tried adding different if-statements to try and specify what is unique and what is a copy. This would typically help in filling the array with the correct number of integers, but not the unique ones. It seems to be skipping quite a few unique integers and filling the array with copies. I am pretty stuck, and any suggestions whatsoever would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know how to use a step-by-step debugger?

Comment: (in this case there's a clear issue: you never reset your ID flag. A run through a debugger would have made that fairly obvious)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented on your code and you changed it, then should work.

> ```
> private static int read(String inFileName, int[] list) {
>     int size = 0;
>     int i= 0;
>
>     Scanner inFile = null;
>     int val = 0;
>
>     int trash = 0;
>  // boolean ID = false;  remove 
>     int Unique = 0;
>     int dupe = 0;
>     int lineCount = 0;
>
>     try { 
>         inFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
>         while (inFile.hasNext()){
>             boolean ID = false; // Add here
>             lineCount++;
>             try{
>                 val = inFile.nextInt();
>                 if(val < 0) { 
>                     trash++;
>                     continue; 
>                 }
>
>                 for(i = 0; i< size ;i++){ 
>                     if(list[i] == val){
>                         ID = true;
>                         dupe++;
>            
>                     }
>
>                 }
>                 if (ID == false && size<list.length){ 
>                     list[size] = val;
>                     size++;
>                     Unique++;
>                 }
>
>             }
>             catch (InputMismatchException e){
>                 trash++;
>                 inFile.nextLine();
>             }
>
>         }
>         System.out.println("lines: " + lineCount + ", unique: " + Unique +  ", dupes: " + dupe + ", trash: " + trash);
>     }
>     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>         System.out.println("Error in opening " + inFileName);
>     }
>
>
>     return size;
> }
> ```